# Proving that $ \int \left| f-g \right|~d\mu = 2\int_{A_0} (f-g)~d\mu$

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Given a (dominant) measure $\mu$, consider two probability measures $f~d\mu$ and $g~d\mu$ over $(\Omega, \mathcal F)$, I'd like to check the following reasoning for showing that

$$ \int \left| f-g \right|~d\mu = 2\int_{A_0} (f-g)~d\mu$$

where $A_0 = \{f \geq g \}$

My solution is : Conditionally to $A_0$, we have that

$$\int \left| f-g \right|~d\mu = \int_{A_o} (f-g)~d\mu+\int_{A_o^C} (g-f)~d\mu$$

But $$\int_{A_0^C}g~d\mu = \int g~d\mu -\int_{A_0}g~d\mu$$
and $$-\int_{A_0^C}f~d\mu = \int_{A_0}f~d\mu -\int f~d\mu$$
so
$$ \int \left| f-g \right|~d\mu = 2\int_{A_0} (f-g)~d\mu+ \int(g-f)~d\mu$$
which give us the wanted result since the second therm in the left side vanishes ( $f ~d\mu$ and $g ~d\mu$ are both probability measures).

Please enlighten me if I am making any mistake.
Thank's in advance.

Comment: @Landscape :Indeed. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: The proof is fine, and the crucial here is that $\int f \mathrm d\mu = \int g\mathrm d\mu$ which is satisfied in your case since both measures are probability measures.